# CTE looping query

Tags: sql, loops, with-statement

First I'll explain you the situation.

I want to transfer data from one table(View_Solidnet_Training) to another(OBJ_Availability).
There is one problem: In the view there is a Start- and EndDate! In `OBJ_Availability` every date has one record. So one line  in the view has multi lines in the other table.

I must work with CTE. So cursor is no option for me.
The middle `WITH` runs perfect, but when I want to add an extra `WITH` to check if the `ID` isn't zero, it must change the variable `@Start` and `@End` to the new record in the view.

Sorry for my English, it isn't that good but I hope you understand the situation.

here is my code:

```
DECLARE @Start AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @End AS DATETIME;
SET @Start = '2013-04-09';
SET @End = '2013-04-11';
with cte1 as 
(

with cte2 as
(
select @Start as DateValue
union all

select DateValue + 1
from cte2
where DateValue + 1 <= @End
)
into OBJ_Availability  
select 34, DateValue, 'AM', 2, 'Test' from cte2
)
select * from cte1 where PK_Training_ID is not null;
```

Something like this, but I don't understand where it gets the information of the view. I never mentioned the name anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not make comment yet, so I need to ask you few questions before answering.

1, how come the CTE's name is the same as the view's name? it should never work.

2, what do you mean by 'check if the ID isn't zero, it must change the variable @Start and @End to the new record in the view', I could not figure out why you need to do the null check

3, you sure you can use DateValue + 1 to get next date? should you be using DATEADD?

lastly, you cannot have a CTE inside a CTE, this is not going to work. Declare variable in CTE is not possible neither.

**here is my best guest:**

firstly, as you mentioned that your view has a startdate column and a enddate column,

so I assume there are StartDate and EndDate columns in the view, here is my sql:

```
DECLARE @start AS DATETIME
DECLARE @end AS DATETIME

SELECT @start = min(StartDate)
from View_Solidnet_Training 
where PK_Training_ID is not null

SELECT @end = max(EndDate) 
from View_Solidnet_Training 
where PK_Training_ID is not null

;with cte_dates as
(
    select @start DateValue
    union all
    select DateValue + 1
    from cte_dates
    where DateValue + 1 <= cast(@end as datetime)
)
into OBJ_Availability  
select v.PK_Training_ID, DateValue, 'AM', 2, 'Test' --columns from the view
from cte_dates cte
join View_Solidnet_Training v on v.StartDate < cte.DateValue and cte.DateValue < v.EndDate 
where v.PK_Training_ID is not null
```

the max() and min function figure out that newest and oldest date in the view

then the CTE cte_dates creates a list of dates from the @start to @end

then the join to the CTE will make records repeated within the range from StartDate to EndDate

hope this help

by the way, I do not have sql on my home pc, so I can check if

```
SELECT @start = min(StartDate)
from View_Solidnet_Training 
where PK_Training_ID is not null
```

runs or not, but you should get the idea

**Use while instead of CTE:**

```
DECLARE @start AS DATETIME
DECLARE @end AS DATETIME

SELECT @start = min(StartDate)
from View_Solidnet_Training 
where PK_Training_ID is not null

SELECT @end = max(EndDate) 
from View_Solidnet_Training 
where PK_Training_ID is not null

DECLARE @AllDates table
        (DateValue datetime)

DECLARE @dCounter datetime
SELECT @dCounter = @start

WHILE @dCounter <= @end
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO @AllDates VALUES (@dCounter)
 SELECT @dCounter=@dCounter+1 
END

insert into OBJ_Availability  
select v.PK_Training_ID, DateValue, 'AM', 2, 'Test' --columns from the view
from @AllDates d
join View_Solidnet_Training v on v.StartDate < d.DateValue and d.DateValue < v.EndDate 
where v.PK_Training_ID is not null
```

**or you can even do**

```
DECLARE @start AS DATETIME
DECLARE @end AS DATETIME

SELECT @start = min(StartDate)
from View_Solidnet_Training 
where PK_Training_ID is not null

SELECT @end = max(EndDate) 
from View_Solidnet_Training 
where PK_Training_ID is not null


DECLARE @dCounter datetime
SELECT @dCounter = @start

WHILE @dCounter <= @end
BEGIN

    insert into OBJ_Availability  
    select v.PK_Training_ID, DateValue, 'AM', 2, 'Test' --columns from the view
    from View_Solidnet_Training v
    where v on v.StartDate < @dCounter and @dCounter < v.EndDate and v.PK_Training_ID is not null

    SELECT @dCounter=@dCounter+1 
END
```

Comment: 1, Didn't know that

2, This moment after inserting one line of the view it stops. So I must make a new loop to check if there is another line, he must set the variables with the new values and change them to insert the next line. 

3, This is true, it works.

4, But I need to make loop in loop because after the first insert, he must changes the dates and start again with inserting the next in the view.

Comment: one more question, where is the PK_Traing_ID came from? does not belong to OBJ_Availability?

Comment: but your view is just a CTE which has only one column 'DateValue', can you provide info on how the view get created?

Comment: no, but the name of the CTE is the name of my View with all the information. Somebody tolds me it is not legal, so I'll change it!

Comment: ok, cool, maybe you can update the question with your changes, and I will have a look

Comment: I have update my answer, have a look, and let me know if my guest is right or not

Comment: I don't understand the join? The only way to join is on prim and foreign key?

ps: error: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: The condition of join can be anything which returns a bool, so this join will make records in the view repeated. Now, our issue is that the cte cannot run too many recursions but there are too many dates. I will update the answer, and I don't think we need cte

Comment: There are two more options for you, choose the faster one I will say

Comment: Datevalue? Where do you declare this?
Should I replace it with @dcounter?

Comment: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'on'.

Comment: Not a prob, glad to help:)